# adding carriage return don't put the string that follows it at the begining position

Tags: javascript, carriage-return

I wanted to understand what carriage return is by writint a simple code to console.As carriage return '\r' means

> " return to the beginning of the current line without advancing
>   downward"

But in my code the following string is appended at the end of the line .Why it is behaving like this.I have a string `"this is my string"` ,then i have carriage return ,and it is followed by another string `"that"`.I thought `"that"` will be placed at the beginning of the string

```
console.log("this is my string"+String.fromCharCode(13)+"that");
```

it prints `"this is my stringthat"`

Comment: Which console are you logging to?

Comment: I think you want `\n` not `\r`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `\r` in a string in JavaScript is probably going to give you different results depending on a combination of how the program is being run (in a browser or a standalone engine) and the target of the text (`console`, `alert`, a text node in an HTML element etc). It's not clear from your question whether you're running JavaScript in a browser, but (assuming you are) you're going to get different results for different browsers. Internet Explorer's `console` treats `\r` as a newline character (`\n`) while most other browsers will ignore it. I doubt *any* browser implementation of `console` is going to give you the behavior you've described.

Note that `\r` is not a string processing instruction, it's a **character**. Doing this:

```
var aString="one\r2";
```

is never going to result in

```
aString == "2ne"
```

or

```
aString == "2one"
```

or

```
aString == "one2"
```

or anything similar evaluating to `true`. `aString`'s value will remain `"one\r2"` until you change it. It's up to the `console` or `alert` that is displaying the string to choose how to render `\r`.

There are string processing methods in JavaScript for splitting and recombining strings (see the [w3schools Javascript String Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_string.asp) or [Mozilla's String reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String)) that would better suit your purposes. If you start using characters like `\r` or `\b` in other languages and/or environments you're going to encounter different behaviors based on a whole host of factors.